# Why does the console return the correct data, but not the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

When running `get_style_guide_version()` the console will return the expected data, but what prints in the browser is `undefined`. Why is that?

```
function get_style_guide_version() {

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON( '/package.json', function() {
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        output = data.version;
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    });

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.write(get_style_guide_version());
});
```

Comment: because its an ajax call, which is asynchronous. Also, your function doesn't return, that's why its printing undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the document ready function you are trying to write the results of get_style_guide_version(), which is running an async process

So the function completes before the async has returned so that wont work.

What you should do is have another function that is called manually that writes to the document and is called when the .done promise fires.

```
function get_style_guide_version() {

var jqxhr = $.getJSON( '/package.json', function() {
})
.done(function(data) {
    output = data.version;
    console.log(output);
    write(output);
});

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.write(get_style_guide_version());
});

function write(val){
    document.write(val);
}
```

or

```
function get_style_guide_version(done) {

var jqxhr = $.getJSON( '/package.json', function() {
})
.done(function(data) {
    output = data.version;
    console.log(output);
    done(output);
});

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
   document.write(get_style_guide_version(function(val){
      document.write(val);
   }));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is two issues with the code:

- The function actually returns nothing. Your `return` statement is inside the `.done()` function of your ajax request.
- That request is done asynchronously and will most certainly not have been completed before your `get_style_guide_version` completes.

If you did the document.write part instead of the console.out, it would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, its an asynchronous request, function wont wait for the success event to happen..

Answer (score 0):

When you write `return output`, you are returning in the `done()` callback. Not in the `get_style_guide_version` method.

You should use another callback to write the `output` in your browser.